# Dynamically creating route helper in Rails 4 controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to DRY up my access control tests, since I call the same ones for every action.

My program creates a separate subdomain for each account. When a logged-in user from subdomain 'foo' tries to access a page on subdomain 'bar', they get redirected over to the same page on subdomain 'foo'.

Here's what a typical access control test looks like:

```
test "on admin page, logged-in user from other subdomain redirects" do
  # log-in the user and other setup here...
  get :admin
  assert_redirected_to admin_url(subdomain: other_users_subdomain)
end
```

Works just fine, but I want to stop copying and pasting this for every single action by doing something like this:

```
["all", "my", "action", "names", "go", "here"].each do |method_name|

  test "on #{method_name} page, logged-in user from other subdomain redirects" do
    # log-in the user and other setup here...
    get method_name.to_sym
    assert_redirected_to send("#{method_name}_url".to_sym, subdomain: other_users_subdomain)  
  end

end
```

However, this doesn't work thanks to the `send`. For each test, I get an error message like this:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'admin_url' for #<ShopsControllerTest:0x0000010643fbf0>
```

I've been trying to find what exactly the *_url helpers are a method of so I can get this working, but no dice so far. Any suggestions?

EDIT: I'd still love to get the *_url helpers working, but the work-around is to call `assert_redirected_to` like this:

```
assert_redirected_to action: method_name, subdomain: other_users_subdomain
```